# Prevent SQL from over-optimising constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

My question: is there a way to tell SQL Server: optimise(query part A), optimise(query part B) and ONLY THEN return the intersection of the two? Currently it is optimising(A+B), and the result of that is 30x slower, when compared to executing the two parts of the query.

I could look at the execution plan of the combined query and add indexes/try to restructure it etc., but that is not my question here. Is there an alternative to that - maybe there's some query engine hints I could add? or another way I could restructure the query so the engine doesn't try to optimise it as a whole?

I have two queries that separately run in a few seconds and return only a few rows. When I combine them into a single query, it executes for 5+ minutes.

```
SELECT trk.* 
FROM dbo.[vwNewRMA] trk 
WHERE trk.[Repair Centre] = 'US' 
  AND trk.IsWorkOrder IS NULL
```

Part A, runs in **5 seconds** and returns **240 rows**.

```
SELECT Customer 
FROM [RMACustomer] 
WHERE [USServiceCenterCustomer] = 1
```

Part B, runs in **1 second** and returns **32 rows**

However, when I try to filter the first record set by the second, my best attempt takes **more than 5 minutes**:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT trk.* 
     FROM dbo.[vwNewRMA] trk 
     WHERE trk.[Repair Centre] = 'US' 
       AND trk.IsWorkOrder IS NULL) t1
WHERE 
    t1.Customer IN (SELECT Customer 
                    FROM [RMACustomer] 
                    WHERE [USServiceCenterCustomer] = 1)
```

**More than 16 minutes**:

```
SELECT trk.* 
FROM dbo.[vwNewRMA] trk 
WHERE trk.[Repair Centre] = 'US' 
  AND trk.IsWorkOrder IS NULL 
  AND trk.Customer IN (SELECT Customer 
                       FROM [RMACustomer] 
                       WHERE [USServiceCenterCustomer] = 1)
```

**More than 16 minutes**:

```
SELECT trk.* 
FROM dbo.[vwNewRMA] trk 
INNER JOIN [RMACustomer] cust ON cust.Customer = trk.Customer 
                              AND cust.[USServiceCenterCustomer] = 1
WHERE trk.[Repair Centre] = 'US' 
  AND trk.IsWorkOrder IS NULL
```

Is there a trick I could use to combine them into a single statement that forces the query engine to not overthink it?

Comment: Have you looked at the **actual execution plans** for these combined queries? That should give you an idea of where the time is spent / lost ...

Comment: How many rows does the relevant tables have? What kind of indexes do they have?
Also, Out of curiosity, What happens if you hard code the 32 rows returned from the second query into the first query that takes more than 16 minutes?

Comment: @marc_s, yes, the query plan for the view vwNewRMA is a mess. It contains queries on other views and lots of inefficiencies (I didn't write it :)). But that query run on its own, only takes 5 seconds. The other 1 second. Is there a way I can join these so it takes <10 seconds without modifying the view?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I appreciate that I could optimise the view vwNewRMA (and add suggested indexes etc.), but that's a lot of work. I'm looking for a trick to stop the query engine from pulling the second query into the first, slowing it down. I would like it to optmise the first query (5 sec), optimise the second query (1 sec) and only then join the two result sets

Comment: @ZoharPeled Using hardcoded names in the `IN ()` takes 5 seconds

Comment: Your (presumably) `VIEW` `vwNewRMA` doesn't reference any other views in its definition, does it?

Comment: @ThomA Yes, it does

Comment: That might well be your problem, nesting views can easily end up causing problems like this.

Comment: @ThomA Yes, that's definitely the cause; I know this is the problem. My question here is asking does anyone know if there is any other way of structuring my query to avoid the query engine optimising this way, given the two parts run quickly when they aren't combined. I feel like there must be optimisation flags or some trick to tell the engine to optimise only one part, and only then continue processing the rest of the query

Comment: If there were, then the recommendation of not using nested views wouldn't exist because of such a feature. You could I sent your 2 separate statements into temporary tables and join those, while (in the long run) you unnest your view(s) and optimise from there.

Comment: We can't really help you much without execution plans, please share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Please also show the full table and index definitions.

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks, but the question isn't about optimising a particular query, I can do that. The question is, is there an alternative approach in this situation

Comment: Well the alternative approach *is* to optimize the query. If the engine had optimal methods to calculate the two base queries it wouldn't be tempted to choose a bad plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try using `TOP` or `OFFSET` to encourage some separation of the two subtrees.

You might also get better results with `ORDER  BY Customer` than `ORDER  BY (SELECT 0)` as then potentially they can be merged joined together and this might make it less likely that it chooses unspooled nested loops and repeatedly re-evaluates one part.

```
WITH PartA
     AS (SELECT trk.*
         FROM   dbo.[vwNewRMA] trk
         WHERE  trk.[Repair Centre] = 'US'
                AND trk.IsWorkOrder IS NULL
         ORDER  BY (SELECT 0)
         OFFSET 0 ROWS),
     PartB
     AS (SELECT Customer
         FROM   [RMACustomer]
         WHERE  [USServiceCenterCustomer] = 1
         ORDER  BY (SELECT 0)
         OFFSET 0 ROWS)
SELECT *
FROM   PartA a
WHERE  a.Customer IN (SELECT b.Customer
                      FROM   PartB b)
```

e.g. [compare the execution plans here](https://dbfiddle.uk/AvCNp6go)

[image]

But unless you are using this in some context that disallows temp tables I'd just do that as it is more reliable and also assists with more accurate cardinality estimation.

Comment: Your query ran in 5 seconds. Did exactly what I was looking for

Comment: FYI, across a small sample size of 5 executions of `ORDER BY (SELECT 0)` vs `ORDER BY CUSTOMER`, `ORDER BY CUSTOMER` ran approximately 1 second faster

Answer (score 2):

One simple trick you can try is just use a temporary table to store the results of one query and then join that to the results of the second query:

```
SELECT trk.* INTO #TempTrk
FROM dbo.[vwNewRMA] trk 
WHERE trk.[Repair Centre] = 'US' 
AND trk.IsWorkOrder IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM #TempTrk
INNER JOIN [RMACustomer] cust 
    ON cust.Customer = #TempTrk.Customer 
WHERE cust.[USServiceCenterCustomer] = 1;

DROP TABLE #TempTrk;
```

You might want to wrap the entire thing in a transaction with serializable lock to prevent changes in the data between running both queries.

BTW, you really shouldn't use `SELECT *`, but rather specify the column names in your query.

Comment: Upvoted for your efforts. I have various work arounds, similar to above, just asking the question to see if there was some sort of advanced query optimisation I wasn't aware of.